# Storing small (1.0E-12) numbers as doubles in scientific notation

Tags: c, double, scientific-notation

Here's the setup:

For my Bachelor's thesis, I want to test jet algorithms used at the LHC. Basically the first step is the folowing: Given some 4-momentum

```
p[0] = nullvector(45.0000000000106,33.03951484238976,14.97124733712793,26.6317895033428)
```

I want to simulate experimental data by adding some (like, 50) randomly generated 4-vectors to the last three components in the order of 10^(-12), so that they are small (that's where the interesting physics happens), but significantly above the double float precision of 15 decimals. So the quick-and-dirty solution to that is the following:

```
seed=time(NULL);
srand(seed);
random=(rand()%9001)*1.0E-15;
random=random+1E-12;
printf("%.15E\n",random);
```

This gives me random numbers between 1E-12 and 10E-12 (=1E-11) with three decimals max, so that in "real" doubles, that gives me 15 decimals.

Now to the point: **Can I store numbers in that order with more than three decimals without overstepping double float precision?**

PS: Is there a better way to generate small random numbers? (This sounds like another topic ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional method for creating floating point random numbers is to make it a range [0-1) by taking `double x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;` - then multiply by `9001E-1` to scale your range to the `1E-12` to `1E-15` values [zero inclusive].

Comment: Nice, thanks! Is there any reading on why the "traditional method" uses integer division instead of the modulus?

Comment: Sorry, missed to cast one side of the divide to float... Modulo will, as you point out create an integer number (in your case in the range 0..9001, which you then multiply to make it much smaller, but it will largely only give 3 decimal places. The divide method does give a larger range of fractions, since RAND_MAX is typically 2^31-1, which gives a potential for a large number of decimal places to be "filled in".

Comment: I see, with the typecast the thing is consistent and solves the decimal problem :) Cheers!

Comment: In additionm in many traditional implementation of rand() the low bits didn't have good entropy - they were often cyclic, so you got better results by doing the integer division (even if you only wanted an integer from 0-10)

Comment: There are at least three problems with using remainder with `rand`: It discards some bits (mentioned above by Mats Petersson), there is poor entropy with poor generators (mentioned above by Frederick Cheung), and the distribution is non-uniform (the residues up to `RAND_MAX%YourQuotient` occur 1/RAND_MAX more often than others).